# Jquery: Select two equal numbers on two different places and then apply css background yellow

Tags: jquery

i have a table, inside of it here is a tr that has a td which contains "4a.Contrata". That same tr has a td with a price like "$125.45" and that price is the same number as ANOTHER td that is inside the table. 
What i want to do is add a css background yellow to those equal two prices.

Right now all im doing is adding a yellow background to the tr where "4a.contrata" is.

Here is the html of the description i made before, basically im trying to add yellow background to $162,87 (this number varies so i need to "select" this) both the price that is inside the table and the one that is right next to "4a.Contrata"

http://jsfiddle.net/GBqWu/4/

The price will change not only the number but the position. The logic i need toe express is: If a td is the same as the td that is inside the tr that contains 4a.Contrata then apply yellow background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a simpler method:

```
var value = $.trim($("#fichadelcontacto tr:contains('4a.Contrata') td:eq(1)").text());
$('#fichadelcontacto table td:contains("'+value+'")').css("background", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to highlight any matching cell, which may be in any arbitrary position, you can do something like:

```
var number = "$" + $("#fichadelcontacto tr:contains('4a.Contrata')").text().replace(/[\r\n\t ]+/gim, '').split("$")[1];

jQuery.each($("#fichadelcontacto td"), function() {
    if ($(this).text().replace(/[\r\n\t ]+/gim, '').indexOf(number) == 0) {
        $(this).css("background", "yellow");
    }
});
```

Here's a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/GBqWu/7/